# make css only one element selectable

Tags: jquery, css

i have this some elements listed:

```
<ul class="ui-selectable">
<li data-id=100.100></li>
<li data-id=101.100></li>
<li data-id=102.100></li>
<li data-id=103.100></li>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/24/

at this moment you have the oppurtunity to choose more than one listelement.

How to change this, so you can only chose one listelement? greetings!

Comment: remove them from list?

Comment: could you explain maybe via jsfiddle?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/99RUp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
    $('.ui-selectable .selected:not([data-id=""])').removeClass('selected');
```

on your click function http://jsfiddle.net/sirtimid/6KNRc/28/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
    if($('.ui-selectable .selected').length == 0 || $(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().trigger('update');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/26/

Comment: yeah thats what i thought about, but after you selected one listelement, you should have the oppurtunity to select an other one, you understand what i mean? :) greetings!

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you exactly want with your jsFddle we can select more than one item in mine you can only select one and deselect it

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can easily achieve it by checking whether any `li items` have that `selected` class or not.</s>

<s>if(!$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').hasClass('selected'))
{
    //Your code
}</s>

### <s>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/25/)</s>

I was initially misunderstood your need, I think you want that selected black element should occur only once in that li collection. Then please try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6KNRc/30/).

```
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
    $('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function () {
    if ($('.selected').not(this).length>0) return
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qcWhL/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="ui-selectable active">  //add class active
```

and change script to

```
$('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function (e) {
if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().trigger('update');
    $(e.target).parent().removeClass('active').addClass('deactive')
} 

else {
$(e.target).parent().children('li.selected').removeClass('selected')
    $(e.target).parent().removeClass('deactive').addClass('active')
    $(e.target).trigger('click')
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/6KNRc/29/)